# Botão Aplicar - Celulas visíveis

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

Eu tenho um formulário onde há um Listview, e textbox para input de dados e já pelo login eu consigo filtrar uma coluna, pra aparecer apenas os campos que eu quero.

Onde vem o problema ? a intenção é, eu clicar na linha do ListView, inputar os valores de previsto e realizado e esse aplicar, colocar esse valor tanto no Listview (Que está funcionando) e **Adicionar na linha filtrada no excel** (que é o problema)

Ele não puxa a célula que eu selecionei, ele sempre joga na 1 célula do excel.. então no caso, acredito eu que preciso de alguma forma que este botão insira apenas valor na célula visível que eu selecionei.

Segue o print do formulário e o código do botão aplicar!
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
Private Sub CommandButton5_Click()
    Sheets("Treinamentos Tableau").Select

    Dim PosiçãoAtual As Variant
    PosiçãoAtual = Treinamentos.SelectedItem.Index + 1

    Cells(PosiçãoAtual, 3).Value = TextBox6.Text
    Cells(PosiçãoAtual, 4).Value = TextBox7.Text


    With Treinamentos
        .SelectedItem.SubItems(2) = TextBox6.Text
        .SelectedItem.SubItems(3) = TextBox7.Text
    End With   

End Sub
```

---------------- EDIT, EXPLICAÇÃO COM OS PRINTS ---------------

**Explicação 1 : Eu fiz o login e a senha, com uma unidade e ele filtrou apenas aquela unidade, correto ? logo eu vou clicar em cima da linha que quero, colocar os valores de previsto e realizado no textbox e clicar em aplicar.**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Explicação 2 : Cliquei em aplicar, no listview, ele foi no local correto, show, tá em taquari, dezembro como foi a linha que selecionei**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Explicação 3 : Quando eu vou na planilha do excel, ele não puxa a linha filtrada que eu inputei o valor, ele ta indo pra linha que eu não filtrei, que no caso tão pegando então as linhas invisíveis após eu aplicar o filtro**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não entendi muito bem, possui um [mcve]?

Comment: Coloquei uma explicação agora, completa e com prints Daniel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Problema

Você está inserindo na planilha "Treinamentos Tableau" a posição da tabela ListView, porém,  não é essa que deve ser procurada. Pois os índices da ListView mudam ao filtrar, ou seja, não são os mesmos da planilha.

#### Solução

Realizar um loop nas células visíveis da planilha e verificar se a coluna "E" é igual ao valor selecionado `Treinamentos.SelectedItem.SubItems(1)`. Se sim, preenche as colunas "C" e "D" com os valores de `TextBox6.Text` e `TextBox7.Text`, respectivamente.

#### Código

Este código de exemplo possui a parte de Autofiltro para a unidade, porém, como este filtro já é realizado. Esta parte pode ser retirada do código.

A explicação do código está comentado no mesmo.

```
Sub teste()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim unidade As String, data As String
    Dim UltimaLinha As Long, linha As Long
    Dim VisibleRange As Range
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Treinamentos Tableau")
    'Inserir unidade, no seu caso o valor para filtrar
    unidade = "b"
    
    With ws
        'Encontra a ultima linha da coluna A
        UltimaLinha = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        
        'Filtro Unidade
        .Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=unidade
        
        On Error Resume Next
        Set VisibleRange = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(UltimaLinha, 1)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        If Not VisibleRange Is Nothing Then
            'Loop nas células visíveis após aplicação do AutoFiltro
            For Each Cell In VisibleRange
                'Linha
                linha = Cell.Row
                'Verifica se a coluna 5, ou seja, coluna Data é igual ao selecionado
                If Treinamentos.SelectedItem.SubItems(1) = .Cells(linha, "E") Then
                    'Se sim, escreve na célula de mesma linha
                    .Cells(linha, 3).Value = TextBox6.Text
                    .Cells(linha, 4).Value = TextBox7.Text
                End If
            Next
        End If
        '"zera" o autofiltro, mostrando todos dados filtrados
        If .FilterMode Then
            .ShowAllData
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```